# Persist variables using Newman?

Tags: environment-variables, postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I know using Collection Runner in Postman you're able to check a 'Persist variables' checkbox. Is there any way of achieving this when using their cli tool Newman?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually found that you can get desired outcome with adding `--export-environment` like so:

```
newman run coll.json -e env.json --export-environment env.json
```

Link to a Github-issue [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/issues/831).

Answer (score 0):

You can also persist variables ***during*** the collection run with a call to the Postman API to update the environment. See [Persist variables between runs](https://blog.postman.com/how-to-persist-postman-variables/#persist-variables-between-runs), and [this code sample](https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/1559645-374325e1-34cd-447c-8fda-66f1a8cc7cb5).

> To programmatically persist variables in a collection-based monitor or while using Newman, you can include a separate API call to the Postman API within your collection to update the environment storing the variable.